# STL algorithms with templated functions as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm, template-function

How is it possible to use a **templated functions** with the **STL** provided algorithms in `<algorithm>`?
For example, this code does not compile because compiler can't deduce template parameters for the `predicate` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template< typename CharType >
bool predicate( const CharType& c )
{
    return c == '0';
}

std::string
process_string( const std::string& str )
{
    std::string result;
    std::copy_if( str.begin( ),
                  str.end( ),
                  std::back_inserter( result ),
                  predicate );
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << process_string("AK0NNDK0ASDAS0") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide the type: `predicate<std::string::value_type>`

Answer (score 6):

Several ways: including

- provide explicitly the type

  ```
  predicate<std::string::value_type>
  ```
- use lambda

  ```
  [](auto&&e) { predicate(e); }
  ```

Comment: `auto&&` is more generic, but not required in this particular case.

Comment: Unfortunately, the lambda code doesn't work in c++11, which is a tag in the question.  generic lambda's do work from c++14 on.

Answer (score 1):

A template itself can not be a function argument. In this case you want to pass a function pointer to the template function, which you have to instantiate as `predicate<char>`:

```
std::copy_if( str.begin( ),
              str.end( ),
              std::back_inserter( result ),
              predicate<char> );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an instantiated functor w/ a templated `operator()`:

```
namespace detail {

struct predicateFunctor {
    template<typename CharType>
    bool operator()(const CharType& c)
    {
        return c == '0';
    }
};

} /*namespace detail*/

static auto predicate = detail::predicateFunctor{};

std::string process_string(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string result;
    std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(result), predicate);
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << process_string("AK0NNDK0ASDAS0") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b089273aee92179)

Answer (score 0):

use `static_cast` to resolve overload issue:

```
std::copy_if( str.begin( ),
              str.end( ),
              std::back_inserter( result ),
              static_cast<bool (*)(const char&)>(predicate) );
```